AS3 - External SWF file not being loaded in
I'm trying to load in an external SWF file which is being hosted on a webserver i run. If i go to http://localhost:5173/file.swf in the webbrowser the file gets downloaded. I've turned on my server logs and when running the preload.swf file in flash player, i can see a network request in my debug terminal on vscode. i'm not really sure why my external file isn't getting loaded, any suggestions?
i've left out some other functions that have no use in this current context.
public function PreLoader()
      {
         Security.allowInsecureDomain("*");
         this.loaderScreen = new LoaderScreen();
         this.loaderScreen.x = 0;
         this.loaderScreen.y = 0;
         this.myLoader = new Loader();
         addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,this.fade);
         this.loaderScreen.go_btn.visible = true;
         this.loaderScreen.back_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,this.btnCheck);
         this.loaderScreen.next_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,this.btnCheck);
         var myRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://localhost:5173/file.swf");
         this.myLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS,this.showProgress);
         var context:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext();
         context.applicationDomain = new ApplicationDomain(ApplicationDomain.currentDomain);
         this.myLoader.load(myRequest,context);
         addChild(this.loaderScreen);
      }

I've tried consulting the flash player docs and the code seems exactly the same to what i'm doing.

First of all, test Event.COMPETE, Event.INIT and HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS — they help to understand what exactly is going on there under the hood.

Thanks for your response! I'm quite new to development in AS3, started trying to recover an old game i used to play. Any suggestions what software is best to use for debugging the swf files? Currently i'm using jpexs. Greetings, Michael

JPEXS is not a debugger. Normally you set up a debug environment that allows you to catch all the trace output, or code a simple debug panel on your own.
